# Error in Microsoft Enterprise Library 6 Unitycontainer

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I am using the following code in project with Enterprise Library 6 and get this error :

> "the type or namespace name 'EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension' could not
>   be found "

How to Fix this error ?

```
var container = new Unitycontainer().Addnewextension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();

container.Registertype<Ilog, logger_enterprise>();

var logger = container.resolve<Ilog>();
logger.log("message");
```

Comment: did you try this `using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity;`

Comment: also check if you are not using `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile` for your project

Comment: in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity namespace not found EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension in Enterprise Library6

Comment: and using .net Framework4.5

Answer (score 2):

According to [Grigori Melnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269538/grigori-melnik) on the [release announcement page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/04/25/just-released-microsoft-enterprise-library-6.aspx),

> The Enterprise Library blocks no longer use the Unity container to resolve instances. You should remove all calls to the AddNewExtension method of the Unity container from your code. If your application currently resolves Enterprise Library objects from the container, you must either manually register the required types in the Unity container, or modify your application to use the static facades in the blocks to configure and retrieve the Enterprise Library objects your application uses.
>
> Also, for other changes, don't forget to check out the [change log](https://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib6ReleaseNotes) and the [Migration Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=290906).

Comment: Tanks . But How to Change this code with StructureMap Container? I am using Logwriter Property in logger_enterpris ctor .

Comment: So, you've switched from Unity to StructureMap now? 

I am still using Enterprise Library 5. I would take a look at the Enterprise Library 6 source code to see how it works now, or just register an instance of LogWriter in the container yourself.